# Lodash replacement for a JS check operation to set value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have been using some code to check the value for a input field which is present at index:1 of an array. It is as below

```
const inputValue=journeyData && journeyData.birthdate && journeyData.birthdate[0]
          ? journeyData.birthdate[0]
          : null,
```

Is there a lodash replacement for the same thing which makes it shorted to write ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) which allows specifying a path and also a fallback. If the path cannot be reached on the object, you get the default value:

```js
function test(journeyData) {
  const inputValue = _.get(journeyData, "birthdate[0]", null);
  return inputValue;
}

console.log( test() );                    // null
console.log( test({}) );                  // null
console.log( test({ birthdate: [] }) );   // null
console.log( test({ birthdate: [42] }) ); // 42
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use native [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). No need for lodash.

```js
const journeyData = { birthdate: [new Date()] };

const inputValue = journeyData?.birthdate?.[0] ?? null;
const inputValue2 = journeyData?.birthdate?.[2] ?? null;

console.log(inputValue);
console.log(inputValue2);
```

Additional documentation

- [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: tried this in my react-project and it says "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Comment: `??` has been in modern browsers for around 2.5 years.

Comment: I had to add a npm lib into  my webpack for that